# await, how it works?

Tags: async-await, dart, flutter

if I have something like:

```
var x = await retrieveData()
if (x!= nil){
do stuff
}
```

where `retrieveData()` does an http request.
The question is: Does the if condition wait for the retrieving data or not? (In a better way, does the if condition always return false or not?)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the if condition "waits". 
The code only continues to execute after the Future returned from `retrieveData` completed.

Without `async`/`await` it would be

```
return retrieveData().then((x) {
  if(x!= null) {
    do stuff
  }
})
```